# PHP : is there a way to forbid use of global/system function in certain class?

Tags: php, laravel, function, global

I am using Laravel and there is a helper function app() (the app() function itself is built in in the framework as a global function and I have no intention to modify it) which in my application I want to keep it usable only inside certain classes and not others.

What I want to do is something like following

```
class Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        forbid_use_of_function('app');
    }

    public function bar() {
        app('SomeService');
    }
}

$foo = new Bar();

// The following line will give error or throw exception 
$foo->bar();
```

Is this even possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To give more context, my code has some internal class functions that uses app to create various instances based on various accessibility restrictions. The code is going to be managed by a variety of other people and not myself. When someone else comes and manage my code, I want to avoid the case that he just does not use my internal functions but just use app() since this is the most convenient way (and unintentionally get around the accessibility restriction check).

Comment: The way to do this would usually be through base classes and protected methods. In PHP, however, you don’t “own” your namespace. To flip the script, if someone uses your code that is _documented_ as conceptually private, what happens?

Comment: In your example it looks like the bar() function could simply give an error rather than using the app() function.  If you are coding the Bar class and you want to prevent it from using app(), can't you just build that into the class?  Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: My problem is that , my code is going to be managed by someone else and not myself in the future. I actually have a protected internal class function that actually uses app(), but then when someone else starts to write the code he can simply use "app" itself instead of my internal function and everything becomes meaningless.

Comment: Well, it's always good to assume that other people will use, extend, debug and modify your code in the future.  You can never prohibit people from doing stupid things but you can give them some help.  If someone wants to use the app() function then they will use it, with our without your class.   Why not comment your code to explain why you wrote the protected function and suggest that people use it rather than app()?

Comment: Whoever uses your code in the future can also write `die` whenever they want. That’s not your problem. You need to have code that executes in a logical manner provided a set of inputs, and ideally is documented.

Comment: There are actually a lot of inheritance happening in my code and if people will look at the base class comment that's fine, however it seems pretty bad to put the same comment in every class that inherits "Bar" and another point is that code reviews become much harder as the reviewer will need to manually check(and remember to check) every single line to make sure no app is used. If something prevents this from happening automatically can be implemented a lot of risk can be avoided and time can be saved.

Comment: Your example does not show any inheritance.  Is app() a function in a separate library that could be used by any class?  Or is it a method in a class somewhere in your hierarchy?  A little more detail on the problem would probably help.

Comment: The "die" analogy is a bit different situation because it is very easily debugged and it is also not a "generally-wide-used" function. Therefore the points I mentioned above does not really apply to that case and I don't feel the need to specifically restrict "die.

Comment: Yes I simplified the example for easy understanding purpose. The app() function comes with the Laravel framework and I have no intention to modify the framework itself.

Comment: OK, so what does it mean to say that a class or subclass cannot use app()?  You can search the source code to see if it contains calls to app() but you have no way to determine with certainty whether app() will be called by a class at runtime, or by something else the class uses.  The only way to be sure is to unload the whole library but then nobody can use it.  I think what you really want is a good service that makes it obvious that people are better off not trying to use app() directly.  Probably also best to avoid inheritance if you can.

Comment: "What does it mean to say that a class or subclass cannot use app?" Ideally what I want is when the bad class calls app() an error will occur, but when some other good class calls app() there will be no error, given the premise that app() itself is fixed and unmodifiable. And this happens all during the same run-time. My question is asking whether this is possible. If you are sure this is impossible you can provide an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to restrict the visibility or accessibility of a function provided by a third-party service so that it is accessible to certain classes and inaccessible to others.  There is no such construct provided by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you cannot stop global functions as per my knowledge. That is already been said. So I writing for 2 reason

1. You should not do that.
2. It still can be achieved.

TLDR;

#1 The good system design depends on good programmer. The ideal way is to give proper documentation to new member and tell them to follow. But knowing how team works and they avoid documentation at time. Second step is for you.

#2 Have code quality setup. In your Repo/git/svn try to put some Code quality rule that reject any code submission that contain those function calls. I am not sure if it can be achieve easily. I never do that. I always believe to let developer do the way they want and train them to use the right way. If they cannot they are not good developer and we don't need them in team anyways.

But for accidental use case we can have Code Quality automations I know Visual Studio has code analysis, PHP has some tools too, maybe word search on commit alter moderator etc to check and reject code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually PhpStorm does have the ability to add custom warning rules and I will consider using it to add warning in addition to the documentation. The problem with large-scale code documentation, based on my real experience, is that there are too many important things to remember even for a good programmer and new comers usually only focus on the specific feature they are working on while not paying too much attention to the "general rule", which takes a lot of time to learn.

Comment: You are right and I had same problem. hence I put my base code as repo so they cannot touch it. (junior do get messy there). and I try not to overwrite base function, at most I hide those special change and club them to something they will use. But as I said those commit check are only way to force it. Rest developers are always intelligent to explore their way.